# xslt регулярное выражение

Tags: xslt

Скажите как с помощью xslt получить текст из xml файла
Смотрите, есть файл пример:

```
<tests>
    <test>_{aaa}</test>
    <test>{bbb}_</test>
    <test>_{ccc}_</test>
    <test>{ddd}</test>
    <test>eee</test>
    <!-- CODE=123 -->
</tests>
```

Как можно получить значение из комментария? ничего не помогает, находил регулярные выражения (analyze-string), но не запускается выдает синтаксическую ошибку. Подскажите как можно?

Comment: xslt какой версии доступно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `comment()` в качестве шаблона:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//comment()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="comment()">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Для извлечения подстроки проще всего использовать функцию `substring-after`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '=')"/>
```

Будет получено значение `123`  - с пробелом на конце.
Если желательно и пробел убрать, добавим функцию `substring-before`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '='), ' ')"/>
```

Comment: А может подскажите еще какрегулярку использовать? Или получить значение code

Comment: просто если несколько там будет переменных, через запятую,

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг - Я не умею мысли читать, я не знаю, какие там данные. Приведите пример.

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг - Кстати, комментарии не предназначены для хранения _данных_. Они для _комментариев_. Поэтому выкиньте такой формат xml.

Comment: xxx=2,rrr=5,fffff=7,asddsdsd=6   викинуть нельзя) и изменять оффициальную структуру тегов нельзя, а вот добавлять комментарий не запрещается, поэтому и выкручиваемся, добавляя часть данных в комментарий

Comment: Добавьте информацию в _вопрос_ (отредактируйте его). И укажите, xslt  какой версии можно использовать. | Таки наймите специалиста по xml. Добавлять свои теги всегда можно: просто назначьте им отдельное пространство имён (они для этого и предназначены). Если у кого-то при этом сломается парсинг - сами виноваты, неймспейсы нужно учитывать всегда.